# Change PHP array to JSON array with Static Index

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have following array values generated By PHP.

```
Array
( [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => 12:00
            [3] => 12:30
            [4] => 13:00
            [5] => 13:30
        )
  [2] => Array
        (
            [2] => 12:00
            [3] => 12:30
            [4] => 13:00
            [5] => 13:30
            [6] => 14:00
        )
)
```

I want to convert this as JSON array values with static index.
If i use `echo json_encode array("Timeslots"=>$arry)`  i am getting following results ,

```
"TimeSlots":{"2":{"2":"12:00","3":"12:30","4":"13:00","5":"13:30"},
         "3":{"2":"12:00","3":"12:30","4":"13:00","5":"13:30","6":"14:00"}}
```

But i want to display json array with static index called as slot instead of 1,2,3 ,,
My Expected Output should be like following ,

```
{
    "TimeSlots":{"2":[{"slot":"12:00"},{"slot":"12:30"},{"slot":"13:00"},{"slot":"13:30"}]},
                 "3":[{"slot":"12:00"},{"slot":"12:30"},{"slot":"13:00"},{"slot":"13:30"},{"slot":"14:00"}]}
}
```

How can i do this.

Comment: That output doesn't work. You assign several different values to the key `slot`, which isn't possible. It would however be possible to make it look something like this: `{"1":{"2":{"slot":"12:00"},"3":{"slot":"12:30"}...`

Comment: You have to transform your original object before you pass it to `json_encode `. Make a copy that matches your desired output.

Comment: @treegarden The output does work. It's valid JSON

Comment: How can you get the following result when you don't even have `[3] => Array` but I do see `"3":{` in your result.

Comment: You're right @maja. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that exact output, your array's index cannot start at `2`, because that means that the json string it creates will always contain the entry's key as well, which apparently you don't want to have in your json string.

If your array starts at 0 and counts upwards, the key's will not be present in the json:

```
$timeslots = array('Timeslots' => array(
    1 => array(
            array('slot'=>'12:00'),
            array('slot'=>'12:30'),
            array('slot'=>'13:00'),
            array('slot'=>'13:30')
         ),
    2 => array(
            array('slot'=>'12:00'),
            array('slot'=>'12:30'),
            array('slot'=>'13:00'),
            array('slot'=>'13:30'),
            array('slot'=>'14:00')
        )
    ),
);
```

Creates the following json:

```
{"Timeslots":{"1":[{"slot":"12:00"},{"slot":"12:30"},{"slot":"13:00"},{"slot":"13:30"}],"2":[{"slot":"12:00"},{"slot":"12:30"},{"slot":"13:00"},{"slot":"13:30"},{"slot":"14:00"}]}}
```

If you want to manipulate your original array in order to create this output, you could do it like this:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$entry) {
    foreach($entry as $subEntry) {
        $newArray[$key][] = array('slot' => $subEntry);
    }
}
$newArray = array('Timeslots' => $newArray);
```

Then `json_encode($newArray)` will get you the same output.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arry = array( 1 => array(2 => '12:00', 3 => '12:30', 4 => '13:00', 5 => '13:30'), 2 => array( 2 => '12:00', 3 => '12:30', 4 => '13:00', 5 => '13:30', 6 => '14:00'));
foreach($arry as $key => $value) {
    $slots = array_values($value);
    foreach ($slots as $key2 => $slot) {
        $slots[$key2] = array('slot' => $slot );
    }
    $arry[$key] = array_values($slots);
}
echo json_encode(array("Timeslots"=>$arry));
```

edit: forgot the "slot" key, this works.